# HTML Tags in GWT internationalization

Tags: gwt, internationalization

I'm using the internationalization of GWT to manage the different languages of my application. I have a text where some words are in bold. Therefore I did the same thing as described [here](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideI18nMessages.html).

```
@DefaultMessage("Welcome back, {startBold,<b>}{0}{endBold,</b>}")
String testMessage(String name);
```

However, when I run the application, I get "Welcome back, < b>Peter< /b>" (the HTML is written out and not interpreted. I intentionally put a space between < b so that this text editor does not interpret the html tag).

Does anyone know how to solve this issue? Many thanks in advance!

P.S.
Code fragment which gets the language string:

```
Label label = new Label(); 
label.addStyleName("intro-Text");
label.setText(new HTML(trans.testMessage(name)).getHTML());
```

Comment: Please show us the code where you actually use the `testMessage(String)` method to display the text. It sounds like you don't use a html sensitive widget (like a `Label` instead of a `HTML`).

Comment: @z00bs I replaced the Label directly with an HTML and it works. If you post your comment as an answer, then I will accept it :)! Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using a `Label` use the `HTML` widget.

```
HTML text = new HTML();
text.addStyleName("intro-Text");
text.setHTML(trans.testMessage(name));
```

Hope that helps.